# Replace YouTube URL in text with its HTML embed code

Tags: php, regex

This function embed youtube videos if found in a string.

My question is what would be the easiest way to only capture the embedded video (the iframe and only the first if there are more) and ignore rest of the string.

```
function youtube($string,$autoplay=0,$width=480,$height=390)
{
preg_match('#(v\/|watch\?v=)([\w\-]+)#', $string, $match);
  return preg_replace(
    '#((http://)?(www.)?youtube\.com/watch\?[=a-z0-9&_;-]+)#i',
    "<div align=\"center\"><iframe title=\"YouTube video player\" width=\"$width\" height=\"$height\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/$match[2]?autoplay=$autoplay\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>",
    $string);
}
```

Comment: The easiest and most robust way would be not using a regex.

Comment: @FailedDev Care to show me how (doesn't have to be the same function)?

Comment: You are passing part of the html with the $string right? How do you get that string?

Comment: I read your question five times, and in my head one question keeps spawning: "What is the input string?"

Comment: The function is currently used for user posts to automatically embed yt videos. I am trying to use the same function (or logic) to let users use youtube videos as their avatars.

Comment: You'll need to provide an example input `$string`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Okay, I think I see what you're trying to accomplish. A user inputs a block of text (some comment or whatever), and you find a YouTube URL in that text and replace it with the actual video embed code.

Here's how I've modified it:

```
function youtube($string,$autoplay=0,$width=480,$height=390)
{
    preg_match('#(?:http://)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?v=)|youtu\.be/)([\w-]+)(?:\S+)?#', $string, $match);
    $embed = <<<YOUTUBE
        <div align="center">
            <iframe title="YouTube video player" width="$width" height="$height" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$match[1]?autoplay=$autoplay" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </div>
YOUTUBE;

    return str_replace($match[0], $embed, $string);
}
```

Since you're already locating the URL with the first `preg_match()`, there's no need to run another regex function for replacing it. Have it match the entire URL, then do a simple `str_replace()` of your entire match (`$match[0]`). The video code is captured in the first subpattern (`$match[1]`). I'm using `preg_match()` because you only want to match the first URL found. You'd have to use `preg_match_all()` and modify the code a bit if you wanted to match all URLs, not just the first.

Here's an explanation of my regular expression:

```
(?:http://)?    # optional protocol, non-capturing
(?:www\.)?      # optional "www.", non-capturing
(?:
                # either "youtube.com/v/XXX" or "youtube.com/watch?v=XXX"
  youtube\.com/(?:v/|watch\?v=)
  |
  youtu\.be/     # or a "youtu.be" shortener URL
)
([\w-]+)        # the video code
(?:\S+)?        # optional non-whitespace characters (other URL params)
```

Comment: I've been searching for this script all over the net. This one works but it only detect the first url in the content. For example, I have 3 youtube urls in the content. The first video will embed while the others just display links. 

What should I do?

Comment: I've got it! Just change `preg_match` to `preg_match_all`... Thanks a millions!

Comment: To further improve this, add https support too :)